# CSV file contains columns with comma while downloading it

Tags: angular, csv

I am working on downloading csv file using angula2, I have done code but the issue is if the column contains comma it is splitting to next column then values are missing in the csv file download. My code is

```
 ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
            var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
            var str = '';
            var row = "";

            for (var index in objArray[0]) {
                //Now convert each value to string and comma-separated
                row += index + ',';
            }
            row = row.slice(0, -1);
            //append Label row with line break
            str += row + '\r\n';

            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var line = '';
                for (var index in array[i]) {
                    if (line != '') line += ','

                    line += array[i][index];
                }
                str += line + '\r\n';
            }
            return str;
        }
```

Comment: please help me to resolve

Comment: did you find a solution?